# Xamarin Forms WebViews await javascript callbacks on iOS and Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, asynchronous, xamarin

I have a `Xamarin` Forms `WebView` that handles Login. When the user logged in, I send a javascript callback with the login session token from the `WebView`(my website) to my `Xamarin` Forms app.

My questions are:

1. If the callback fails to return, how can I handle it in the Xamarin 
   App? How can I retry?
2. How do I pass data from my WebView to my Xamarin app? Should I be 
   using javascript callbacks or something else?
3. Am I implementing Xamarin WebViews correctly?

My implementation is very similar to - https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/HybridWebView

I use an action callback like this:

```
    public void LoginCompleteAction(Action<string> callback)
    {
        loginCompleteAction = callback;
    }
```

I cannot await void. 
If I use TaskCompletionSource won't I be blocking the main thread?